# OpenAI API: Can I remove the line break from the response with a parameter?

Tags: r, openai-api, gpt-3

I've starting using OpenAI API in R. I downloaded the `openai` package. I keep getting a double linebreak in the text response. Here's an example of my code:

```r
library(openai)

vector = create_completion(
  model = "text-davinci-003",
  prompt = "Tell me what the weather is like in London, UK, in Celsius in 5 words.",
  max_tokens = 20,
  temperature = 0,
  echo = FALSE
)


vector_2 = vector$choices[1]

vector_2$text


[1] "\n\nRainy, mild, cool, humid."
```

Is there a way to get rid of this without 'correcting' the response text using other functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The OpenAI API returns the completion with a starting `\n\n` by default. There's no parameter for the [Completions endpoint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions) to control this.

You need to remove the line break manually.

An example response looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "cmpl-uqkvlQyYK7bGYrRHQ0eXlWi7",
  "object": "text_completion",
  "created": 1589478378,
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "choices": [
    {
      "text": "\n\nThis is indeed a test",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "finish_reason": "length"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 5,
    "completion_tokens": 7,
    "total_tokens": 12
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for the answer, I'll remove it manually after then.

Answer (score 0):

There is away to take out the line breaks in the openai response. Add this param to your function

> stop=["\n"]

```
 completion = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=prompt,
    max_tokens=1024,
    n=1,
    stop=["\n"],
    temperature=0.7,
)
```

This will take out the line breaks that come with the response. Hope that helps!

Comment: The text property is an empty string this case. (console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text);) Will not work.

Comment: That is strange because it was working not to long ago. They must have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a restart sequence for the language model to know better how to begin with its answer. The restart sequence may one escaped line break (`\n`) or a white space at the very least.

As the model is completing, it does not want to add the text immediately after the input text, as an answer is not usually appended to the same line of a question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).